# CPU always at 80°C while the system is idle

Tags: cpu, cpu-frequency, temperature

My system is quite unused at the moment:

```
%Cpu(s): 10.3 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.9 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 s
```

but still the temps `sensors` give me are quite high:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +79.0°C  (crit = +88.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
temp1:        +79.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +80.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +80.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +78.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +88.0°C
```

I cannot understand what process is causing the temperatures to be so high.

Comment: It isn't always down to CPU utilization. Is it a physical system? There could be ventilation issues.

Comment: Yes, it's a notebook.

Comment: Can you confirm the temperatures in the BIOS? Want to make sure it's not just a bug with Linux reading the temperatures wrong.

Comment: How old is the notebook and when was the last time you vacuum cleaned it?

Comment: @derobert I'm quite sure the temperature is accurate, as the fan keeps working. It's strange as on Windows the fan is working on a more reasonable level.

Comment: @Fabby the notebook is a couple of years old, I've never cleaned it, but on Windows works nicely it seems.

Comment: Which OS/Power management utilities (and version) are you running?

Comment: @Fabby Linux Mint 14